# How to make square editor tabs (no swt-border-radius) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, css, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

In these modern times, Eclipse's rounded and/or swooshing tabs are beginning to look a little bit quaint.

I was hoping that a suitably placed:

```
swt-corner-radius : 0px
```

in my default.css would do the trick, but I can't seem to affect the main editor tabs no matter what I try.

Anyone know how I should go about achieving this (or even if it's possible?). I'm building an RCP app based on Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting

```css
swt-simple: true;
```

Gets rid of the 'swoosh" (sloping edge).

The standard tab renderer always draws the top left and right corners with a small curve. If you want to replace that you would need to write your own tab renderer - which you can specify using something like:

```css
swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://plugin id/package.TabRendering');
```

but this is quite tricky!

Finally you can always set the outline colors to match the background so they don't show - like this:
[image: Tabs with no borders]

Comment: Thanks Greg, swt-simple: true gets me closer to what I'm after; I will investigate creating my own tab renderer later!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.16 (officially released in 2020-06) supports setting square editor tabs by setting the corner radius to 0:

```
swt-corner-radius : 0px;
```

Note that using any small value below 6px will effectively result in square tabs as well.

Here's how it looks visually:
[image]

See the [platform announcement](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.16/platform.php#square-ctabs) for more information and [bug 538740](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538740) for the technical implementation details.